# Object Passed to Component Becomes Empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-hooks

I am making a simple Quiz app using React Hooks.

I pass a `question` object into a `ResultModel` component.

[image: Passing the question object into the ResultModel]
Here I `console.log` the `question` object before passing it into the `ResultModel` component.

[image: Console.logging question]
Here I `console.log` the `question` object inside of `ResultModel` component.

[image: Console shows that question loses its properties]
Here is the result... I get an empty `question` object.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the curly brackets for destructuring the props. The variable you've called `question` is actually the context object.

The fix is to do this:

```
export default function ResultModal({ isCorrect, question, getQuestion}) {
```

Or if you prefer, don't destructure in the argument list:

```
export default function ResultModal(props) {
  const { isCorrect, question, getQuestion } = props;
```